# invalid literal for int() with base 10 with split

Tags: python

```
h, w = int(input('Enter your height and weight, use space to seperate two values:')).split(' ')
print('your height:', h, '(cm)')
print('your weight: ', w, '(kg)')
bmi = w / (h/100)^2
if bmi < 18.5:
    print('BMI:', bmi, 'under weight')
elif  18.5 <= bmi < 24.9:
    print('BMI:', bmi, 'normal weight')
elif  24.9 <= bmi < 30:
    print('BMI:', bmi, 'over weight')
elif  30 <= bmi < 35:
    print('BMI:', bmi, 'very over weight')
elif 35 <= bmi < 40:
   print('BMI:', bmi, 'obese')
elif bmi > 40:
   print('BMI: ', bmi, 'morbidly obese')
else:
    print()
```

Despite using the correct data types, python refuses to run the code. Gives me that error in the title even though I'm using type of data that

```
bmi = w / (h/100)^2
```

should be able to understand.

Comment: You’re trying to parse `'180 70'` as an int, and then split that int afterwards…

Comment: `input()` returns a list. You can't feed it to `int()` directly. Use a list comprehension to apply `int()` on the individual values.

Comment: @Klaus `input` returns a list‽

Comment: `input` returns a string. You can split that into a list if you want...

Answer (score 2):

The int function cannot convert tuple values to a number
For this purpose, you can use the following code:

```
a = input('Enter your height and weight, use space to separate two values:')
h, w = map(int, a.split(' '))
print('your height:', h, '(cm)')
```

And instead of the command `bmi = w / (h/100)^2` use this :

```
bmi = w / (h/100)**2
```

all code:

```
a = input('Enter your height and weight, use space to seperate two values:')
h, w = map(int, a.split(' '))
print('your height:', h, '(cm)')
print('your weight: ', w, '(kg)')
bmi = w / (h/100)**2
if bmi < 18.5:
    print('BMI:', bmi, 'under weight')
elif  18.5 <= bmi < 24.9:
    print('BMI:', bmi, 'normal weight')
elif  24.9 <= bmi < 30:
    print('BMI:', bmi, 'over weight')
elif  30 <= bmi < 35:
    print('BMI:', bmi, 'very over weight')
elif 35 <= bmi < 40:
    print('BMI:', bmi, 'obese')
elif bmi > 40:
    print('BMI: ', bmi, 'morbidly obese')
else:
    print()
```

Output for `10 20`:

```
your height: 10 (cm)
your weight:  20 (kg)
BMI:  1999.9999999999995 morbidly obese
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: you likely want to specify the number of times to split `h, w = map(int, a.split(' ', 1))`